# Convert single quote string to double quote

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have an object with a few `string` fields.

When I append the values of those fields with a `String Builder` like so

```
            StringBuilder toHash = new StringBuilder();
            toHash.Append(this.Name);
            toHash.Append(this.Description);
            toHash.Append(this.Instructions);
            toHash.Append(this.Type);
            toHash.Append(this.Text);
            toHash.Append(this.Template);
```

I get two slightly different results on client (Blazor WASM) and Server (NET Core API)

On Client (WASM) I get

`'CLIA<p>Descriptions</p><p>Instructions</p>CA<p><strong>CLIA&nbsp; <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></p>CLIA'`

On Server (NET Core API), once the object get posted to the API, I get

`"CLIA<p>Descriptions</p><p>Instructions</p>CA<p><strong>CLIA&nbsp; <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">http://www.google.com</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></p>CLIA"`

Notice that the first string is enclosed in `'`s and not escaped and the second string is enclosed in `"`s and IS escaped.

My hunch is that that it's happening because the second string is the result of a POST request that gets encoded for transport and then the API desterilizes the object with escape characters.

My question is what can I do to either side of this (Client or Server) to ensure those string become exactly the same?

Comment: could you post codes about the variable which get the string value in WASM and webapi?

Comment: It's an POCO object with a bunch of `string` properties `public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Text { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }`, etc. It's the same object on both WASM and API sides

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean convert `'` to `"` at string begining and end?

```
            string s= "'Hello'";         
            var sb =new StringBuilder(s);
            sb[0] = '\"';
            sb[s.Length-1]= '\"';
            s= sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That's not working - the result this is producing is `'"LIA<p>Descriptions</p><p>Instructions</p>CA<p><strong>CLIA&nbsp; <a href="http://www.google.com">http://www.google.com</a>&nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></p>CLI"'` . The string is still in single quotes and not escaped, the double quotes from your suggestions where just added inside the string.

Comment: @americanslon It is supposed to be inside the string. Why would it be outside of the string? That makes no sense. I think you are saying that you can type strings with both single and double quotes. It doesn't matter how they are typed, though, the two are functionally the exact same thing when perceived by your code. There is no such thing as converting from one to the other. They are both the same thing.

Comment: @Caleb I don't believe that's the case. One string is escaped and one is unescaped. The escaped one is the result of NET web api deserializing a POSTed object. They produce different hashes, which indicates they are not identical.